# The requested URL ......... was not found on this server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The home page of my wordpress website seems to be wroking correctly but if you click through to any of the other pages I get the following error message:

The requested URL /about was not found on this server.

There is following htaccess code in the permalink setting:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: //For redirect use this ...


Redirect 301 / your URL/

Comment: Are you using an Apache web server? Is the htaccess in the htaccess file or just listed in the settings and you haven't actually put it there?

Comment: did you enable `rewrite` module and set `AllowOverride All`?

Comment: How to enable the rewite